# Inequality used in proof of continuity of Cantor function (a.k.a. Devil's staircase)

Tags: inequality, uniform-continuity

In my analysis course the lecturer constructs the Cantor function iteratively as is done [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Iterative_construction), then proves that the Cantor function is continuous as follows

\begin{align} \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| & \le \max( \max_{x \in [0, \frac{1}{3})} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|,\max_{x \in [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|,\max_{x \in (\frac{2}{3}, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|) \\
&= \max( \max_{x \in [0, \frac{1}{3})} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|,\max_{x \in (\frac{2}{3}, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|) \\
&= \max( \max_{x \in [0, \frac{1}{3})} |\tfrac{1}{2}f_n(3x) - \tfrac{1}{2}f_{n-1}(3x)|,\max_{x \in (\frac{2}{3}, 1]} |\tfrac{1}{2}f_n(3x-2) - \tfrac{1}{2}f_{n-1}(3x-2)|) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \max_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x) - f_{n-1}(x)|\\
&\le \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-1} \max_{x \in [0,1]}|f_2(x) - f_1(x)|\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n
\end{align}

Where we obtain the second inequality by applying the first n-1 times. He then shows that $(f_n)_{n\ge1}$ is uniformly Cauchy and hence uniformly convergent to the Cantor function, and since each $f_n$ is continuous so is $f$. But, surely equality always holds in the first step, since if $y \in [0,1]$ is such that

$$\max_{x \in [0, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| = |f_{n+1}(y)-f_n(y)|$$

then $y$ will be contained in one of the subintervals $[0, \frac{1}{3}),[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}],(\frac{2}{3}, 1]$, and so

$$\max( \max_{x \in [0, \frac{1}{3})} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|,\max_{x \in [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|,\max_{x \in (\frac{2}{3}, 1]} |f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)|)$$

will be equal to  $|f_{n+1}(y)-f_n(y)|$? Has the lecturer made a mistake? If not can someone give me a reason or proof that equality doesn't always hold?

Comment: Looks like equality does always hold. That doesn't mean the original statement is incorrect, though! Presumably this is in the middle of a string of $\le$s, and the lecturer preferred to keep the relation the same throughout the argument. (My personal preference is to intersperse $\le$ and $=$, to prevent local dissonances like yours, but one sees it done both ways.)

Comment: This is actually the only inequality he uses. I've added the full argument to make my problem clearer.

Comment: Right, so he did use one inequality near the end as well. But basically I agree with you, the very first $\le$ is an $=$, and (while it's a true statement) it would be clearer to write it with $=$.

Comment: Much as I like *the Cantor fiction*, you probably want to fix the typo in the title!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It's enough that equality holds, I was just confused as to why he would write it as an inequality if it was always true. Thanks!